# Change cell format (black out) from a cell with a lookup entry

Tags: excel, vba

Here is what I am trying to do if I can explain it well enough.
I what to black out certain cells by the choice of Column A.

```
Column A is a lookup cell called "equipment".
Column B is diameter
Column C is length
Column D is thread type
Column E is Fuel Type
```

So if they choose `"Hose" in column 1`,  I want them to complete Column B/C/D but E would be blacked out

So if they choose `"Generator" in column 1`, I want them to complete column E with Column B/C/D being blacked out.

Got any suggestions?

Comment: you want to color the cells black?   ...  what is "them"?

Comment: You can change the color of a cell based on a cell's contents with conditional formatting.  If you also want to prevent entries in the cell, you can use VBA to protect/lock/unlock the relevant cells.

Comment: I think he wants to disable/hide it. and maybe "them" he's referring to the users. Please make your question more comprehensive so that you can expect a faster answers/suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this...

Place the following code on Sheet Module. To do that, right click on Sheet Tab --> View Code and paste the code given below into the opened code window --> Close the VB Editor --> Save your workbook as Macro-Enabled Workbook.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
Dim r As Long
If Target.Column = 1 And Target.Row > 1 Then
    r = Target.Row
    Range("B" & r & ":E" & r).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
    Select Case Target.Value
        Case "Hose"
            With Cells(r, "E")
                .Interior.Color = vbBlack
                .Font.Color = vbBlack
            End With
        Case "Generator"
            With Range("B" & r & ":D" & r)
                .Interior.Color = vbBlack
                .Font.Color = vbBlack
            End With
    End Select
End If
End Sub
```